# Why does DjangoFilterBackend returns no results if query value does not exist in my data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using drf and django-filters to perform some filtering on my data. For the filtering backend I use `django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend`.

```
class ProductsViewSet(LoginRequiredMixin, ModelViewSet):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.SessionAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer

    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,
                       rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter,
                       rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter,)
    filter_class = ProductFilter

    search_fields = ("title", "description", "company", "country", "status",)
    ordering_fields = ("title", "description", "company", "country", "status",)
```

My filter_class:

```
class ProductFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    price_from = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr="gte",
                                             label="Min price",
                                             min_value=0)
    price_to = filters.NumberFilter(field_name="price", lookup_expr="lte",
                                          label="Max price",
                                           min_value=0)

    # MultipleChoiceFilters
    country = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name="country", choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES)
    company = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name="company", choices=COMPANY_CHOICES)
    status = filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(field_name="status", choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ["price_from", "price_to", "country",
                  "company", "status"]
    @property
    def qs(self):
        parent = super(ProductFilter, self).qs
        return parent.order_by("-timestamp")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        user_products = Product.objects.filter(user=user)

        # Initial Data #############################################################

        price_min = user_products.all().aggregate(Min("price"))["price__min"]
        price_max = user_products.all().aggregate(Max("price"))["price__max"]

        self.filters["price_from"].extra["initial"] = price_min
        self.filters["price_to"].extra["initial"] = price_max

        COUNTRY_CHOICES = tuple(Product.objects.filter(user=user).values_list("country", "country__name").distinct().order_by("country__name"))
        self.filters["country"].extra['choices'] = COUNTRY_CHOICES

        COMPANY_CHOICES = tuple(Product.objects.filter(user=user).values_list("company", "company").distinct().order_by("company"))
        self.filters["company"].extra['choices'] = COMPANY_CHOICES
```

My issue is that if I try to filter with multiple values and one of them does not exist I get no results.

For example, if I want to filter based on the field company which is a ForeignKey, using 2 values:

- company google with an id=2 does not exist in any of my objects and
- company microsoft with an id =3 that does exist,

the following will return no results

```
api/products?company=2&company=3
```

The same happens if the field is just a CharField. Also, the same behaviour occurs when using filter_fields and filter_class.

At first, I had implemented my own filtering customizing `get_queryset` , but I thought that I might make things less complicated using a filter backend.

I am not sure why this is happening, if the two values that I am filtering with exist everything works fine.

Comment: can you add `ProductFilter` class?

Comment: I have added my filter_class. Although using just filter_fields I get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ProductFilter` class you can specify the method a field uses to run the query. With the filters you'd need to combine those values for the `company` field to search like that. What you're doing is providing to separate values. What you want to do is to change it to do something like;

`api/products?company=2+3`

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    company = django_filters.CharFilter(
        label=_('Company'),
        method='company_filter'
    )

    def company_box_filter(self, qs, name, value):
        """
        Override the filter method in order to lookup for more than one field.
        """
        if not value:
            return qs

        ids = value.split()

        return qs.filter(id__in=ids)
```